# How to include row totals in pivot statement in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a table of data, see 
Using a pivot statement, I am able to break down the count by title

```
select * from (
  select * from ta
)
pivot (
COUNT(title)
 for title in ( 'worker', 'manager') )
```

So the result looks like this:

```
STATUS    'worker'  'manager'
started   3         1
finished  4         5
ready     3         4
```

What I need to add a third column for the row totals

```
STATUS    'worker'  'manager'  Total
started   3         1          4
finished  4         5          9
ready     3         4          7
```

Any idea how I can accomplish this within the same statement?
demo is at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/740fd/1

Answer (score 0):

I would just use conditional aggregation rather than `pivot`. This gives you the extra flexibility that you need:

```
select 
    status,
    sum(case when title = 'worker'  then 1 else 0 end) worker,
    sum(case when title = 'manager' then 1 else 0 end) manager,
    count(*) total
from ta
group by status
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6cd1bb84ca651866cf375509f1045d64)**:

```
STATUS   | WORKER | MANAGER | TOTAL
:------- | -----: | ------: | ----:
started  |      3 |       1 |     4
finished |      4 |       5 |     9
ready    |      3 |       4 |     7
```

Comment: This is a simplified example of a more complicated query that requires pivot

Comment: @dataman: I doubt that it does *require* `pivot`. Everything `pivot` offers can be done with conditonal aggregation (and, actually, more)...

Answer (score 0):

Use the SUM() analytic function to get the total and then use PIVOT

```
select 
    status,
    sum(case 
        when title = 'worker' 
          then 1 
            else 0
        end) worker,
    sum(case
        when title = 'manager' 
          then 1 
            else 0 
        end) manager,
    count(*) total
from ta
group by status
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Give an alias for the whole query(such as `q`) in order to qualify the all columns with asterisk(`q.*`), and then sum up all the columns to yield `total` column next to it :

```
select q.*, worker + manager as total 
  from ta
 pivot 
 (
  count(title)
  for title in ( 'worker' as worker, 'manager' as manager ) 
 ) q
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b41a46060e736bc4973b6c5e8dec5424)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I think the other examples are much simpler, but here is a different approach using `cube` and `grouping` before pivoting:

```
select *
from (
select decode(grouping(title),1,'total',0,title) title,
       status,
       count(*) cnt
from ta
group by status, cube(title) )
pivot(
  sum(cnt) for title in ('worker','manager','total')
)
```

Output:

```
|   STATUS | 'worker' | 'manager' | 'total' |
|----------|----------|-----------|---------|
| finished |        4 |         5 |       9 |
|    ready |        3 |         4 |       7 |
|  started |        3 |         1 |       4 |
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/740fd/13/0

Adding the `cube` into the group by clause will give you a subtotal for that column. It will show as null in that column by default. You can use the `grouping` function in the select clause to differentiate between the total row and the normal rows (the total row will be `1`, normal rows are `0`). Using a decode will force those total rows to be `'total'` which becomes one of the values that you can pivot on.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem for anyone visiting this page:

```
SELECT PVT.*, (COALESCE(PVT."worker",0) + COALESCE(PVT."manager",0)) AS "TOTAL"
FROM
(
select * from (
  select * from ta
)
pivot (
COUNT(title)
 for title in ( 'worker' AS "worker", 'manager' AS "manager") )
)PVT
```

Notes:

1. You can solve the problem by using an additional outer query
2. By aliasing the columns in the pivot clause, you are able to easily call the columns in the outer query
3. Use coalesce in the outer query to return 0 instead of null for the manager and worker columns. This ensures that the total column will always have something to add even though the worker or manager column has null values.